# Windows, batch file time condition

Tags: windows, batch-file

okay, so here is the case, 
i would like to create a batch file, and run it and it will run until a certain time, and then it will execute the commands: ie.

```
if time = 18:00
    netsh interface set interface "Wireless Network Connection" DISABLED
    goto end
end:
close
```

like that?

Comment: Check out the `at` command

Answer (score 0):

You can use "at"

```
at 18:00 netsh interface set interface "Wireless Network Connection" DISABLED
```

Comment: wait... something is not working.....
this is what i've done:                                           

[@echo off
at 18:00 "netsh interface set interface "Wireless Network Connection" DISABLED"
pause]

and what i got what :

[added new job with id=2
press any key to continue]

but then what it's time, nothing happened...

Comment: You're right, sorry, remove the " (fixed on answer)